# Do Node-RED applications using Bluemix IoT Foundation require separate topics for devices and applications?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, node-red

For a Node-RED application, I am using MQTT to talk with the device. Do I need to use two "topics"?:

- One topic for the device to publish information to be subscribed by the Node-Red application.
- One topic for the Node-RED application to publish (and the device to subscribe to).

Alternatively, can both the device and Node-RED application post different information (both publishing and subscribing) to the same topic?

For example: If the device is both publishing temperature data and also subscribing to the same topic to get information from Node-RED in Bluemix, will that cause issues?  There are two types of data I want to exchange:

- The Device would be publishing temperatures.
- The Node-RED application would be publishing "user request" information that would tell the device when to report temperatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two different topics.
Applications (such as Node-RED) that connect to the IoT Foundation service publish commands to devices and subscribe to device events.

The device would subscribe to the command topic, and the application (Node-RED) to the event topic.

Your device will be publishing events – such as temperature. So the device should publish that event to a topic in the format iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string and your Node-RED application will be publishing a command to a different topic.

For example...
You could publish temperatures like this:

iot-2/evt/temperature/fmt/json `{ d: { temp: 25 } }`
and publish commands to the device like this: iot-2/cmd/sendTemperature/fmt/json

The device would subscribe to the command topic, and the application (Node-RED) to the event topic.  Specifically, when you are publishing events, you publish to topic iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string and devices subscribe to commands by subscribing to topic iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string

See the online [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115073651/http://iotf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/messaging/devices.html#publishing-events) for MQTT and IoT.